# JQuery called the Method in the Controller(MVC) twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'll have this code in the index.cshtml

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Create", "ShippingMethods")' data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" data-wrap="modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Edit</a>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Content Inside Here-->
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

And my JQUERY:

```
'use strict';

(function ($) {
     /* Ajax Form Submit for Modal */
    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {

        var $form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.spinner').addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw');
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

            if (data.status == true) {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $target.replaceWith(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    /* Empty Modal Content on Hide */
    $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.modal-content').empty();
        $('.modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-lg modal-sm');
    });

    $('.ShippingMethods')
        .on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function () { // show modal
            $('.modal-dialog').addClass($(this).attr('data-wrap'));
            $('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        })

        .on('submit', '.ajaxForm', ajaxFormSubmit); // modal ajax form submit

})(jQuery);
```

I was wondering why the method in the controller called twice. When in fact I only clicked it once. This function was called twice everytime I clicked the button.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var whs = new PluginManager().GetAllData();
            ViewBag.PluginId = new SelectList(whs, "PluginId", "Description");
            return View();
        }
```

Anyone have idea why it is acting strange? I can't figure out what's the problem in here? Thanks in advance for the help and advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You are not preventing the default behaviour of the link. You have an onclick listener, that makes a call using jQuery's `load`, but after the click listener has been executed, the link will proceed to its default behaviour, which is to follow the link in the `href`, and that's your second call.</strike>

Accept the event as a parameter to your listener, and call `preventDefault` on that to stop your browser from following the link.

```
.on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.modal-dialog').addClass($(this).attr('data-wrap'));
        $('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    })
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I realize that Bootstrap's own listener to `data-toggle="modal"` will prevent the default action for you, so there is no need to do this, as suggested in my inital response.

What you are seeing here, however, is Bootstrap automatically interpreting the value in `href` as a [`remote`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) option, and loads the content for you as well.

Do note that `remote` is deprecated in 3.3, and removed in Bootstrap 4. If you rely on this method, note that it will stop working if you upgrade Bootstrap to a newer version.

My advice would be to take manual control of when, where and how your content is loaded. Do keep your `$('.modal-content').load` call in there, but since Bootstrap is hijacking `href`, you'll need to use something else, such as `data-href`.

Also: I note that you're using `attr('data-...')` to access data attributes. Note that jQuery also exposes these via `data('...')`:

```
<a data-href="@Url.Action("Create", "ShippingMethods")"
  data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target=".modal" 
  data-wrap="modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Edit</a>

.on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function () {
    $('.modal-dialog').addClass($(this).data('wrap'));
    $('.modal-content').load($(this).data('href'));
})
```

Comment: I have called the preventDefault but still calling the method twice. Same result.

Comment: @Jen143: Any errors in the console? Do a `console.log` inside the click listener to determine whether the actual listener is being called twice. Comment out the call to `load` - are you suddenly seeing no calls at all or one that must be coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I did comment out the call to load and it working fine now. It only call once.

Comment: @Jen143: Hey, wait, that was just debugging. Weren't you trying to load the content on that call? It seems that you're now left with just a single call but from an unknown origin. You don't want to leave it like that, you'll want to know how and when and why your action is being called.

Comment: @Jen143: I've realized what's going on with your code. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I've got an error, it will not display the model the second time I'll clicked the button